# On update, skip certain attributes from updating yii

Tags: php, yii, model

i need to stop updating certain value even those are set to POST array. to do that i am using unsafe in yii rules.

```
array('id', 'unsafe', 'on'=>'update'),
```

still with this, i am unable to skip the id from updating.

how can this be done with yii?

below is my rules function..

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('name, body, created_date', 'required'),
        array('name', 'length', 'max'=>128),
        array('body', 'length', 'max'=>512),
        array('id', 'unsafe', 'on'=>'update'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, name, body, created_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

**Update 1**

$model->attributes = $_POST['User'];

and i need when saving, to skip certain attributes.

$model->save();

Comment: Could you add your update function?

Comment: @secretlm its not a function. its a scenario.

Comment: "i need to stop updating certain value even those are set to POST array" => I want to see the code which you set values for model's attributes in "update" action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the new model instance in your controller you will need to declare the scenario 
 for example 
if your declaration was something like this

```
$myModelInstance = new MyModel();
```

you will need to change it to

```
$myModelInstance = new MyModel('update');
```

However if you are using one of the find methods of active records to save it then it is set automatically to "update" as here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail

if you are using some other logic for declaring the model you can simply use the setScenario function

```
$myModel->setScenario("update");
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Manquer, your scenario is probably not set to update. A correct update sequence would involve loading the existing object instance, assigning variables and then saving them. I personally would never just instantiate an object and give it a different scenario, i think that is asking for issues.

```
// Load the existing object first
$user = User::model()->findByPk(..);
// Assign everything that has either a validation rule or is added as "safe"
$user->attributes = $_POST['User'];
// Save the updated version
$user->save();
```

Yii knows not to update the 'id' (if it is correctly defined as the primary key in your database). No need to mark it as unsafe.
So: Make sure that the instance was loaded from the db ($user->isNewRecord should be FALSE) and that the table has a PK. And then update the attributes you want.

You can also only update specific attributes by "cleaning" $_POST first or when you call save just call it as $user->save(true, array('name', 'body')) to only update the name and body for example.

Comment: So there is no other way like, having an unsafe array unsafe('id','created_date') and the attributes that are in unsafe array will not be added or updated and will remain with old values in DB. anything like this that is done from Model level ?

Comment: Since you added the unsafe validator on the "update" scenario you'll have to make sure your model is in that scenario, the way Manquer showed you. I really don't see the point of you using the ActiveRecord pattern like that (as you are circumventing everything :) ). You might just want to use DAO access then (Yii::app()->db->createCommand etc)

Comment: Thanks. anything to say on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142553/model-exist-or-not-in-yii-using-a-custom-function-performance

Answer (score 0):

For **Yii2**:

If one doesn't want to use scenarios because you manually have to apply them, you could either use `when` in `rules()`:

```
['moduleID', 'required', 'when' => function($model, $attribute) {
    return $model->isNewRecord;
}],
```

Or if you have many rules for the attribute and don't want to add `when` to all of them, you could simply prohibit the change in the `beforeSave()` method:

```
public function beforeSave($isInsert) {
    $attribute = 'moduleID';
    if (!$isInsert && $this->isAttributeChanged($attribute)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'You cannot change this.');
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($isInsert);
}
```