# model exist or not in YII using a custom function - Performance

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest, yii

I am writing an REST API and need to check weather the given model name exist or not in the directory.

1 - http://example.com/RestApi/index.php/api/posts/

2 - http://example.com/RestApi/index.php/api/post/

from these two, URL 1 is incorrect and URL 2 is correct (post). so i am taking this param and doing a search as following,

```
  $model = $m::model()->findAll($criteria);
  $m = TK::get('model');
```

when $m is incorrect, PHP warning include(posts.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory will trigger.

so for that not to happen, i have written a function as modelExists() and using it like below.

```
If (!TK::modelExists($m))
            $this->sendResponse(false, 1003);
```

the function body is as below,

```
/**
     * Checks for a given model name
     * @param string $modelName is the name of the model that is used to search against the directory.
     * @return String $result, the name of Model. if doesnt exist NULL;
     */
    public static function modelExists($modelName)
    {
        $result = null;
        $basePath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $modelsDir = 'models'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $modelName = strtolower($modelName).'.php';
        $generalModelDir = scandir($basePath.$modelsDir);

        foreach ($generalModelDir as $entry) { // Searching in General model directory
            if ($modelName == strtolower($entry)) {
                $temp = explode('.', $entry); // array('User','php')
                $result = $temp[0];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$result) {
            $modulePath = $basePath.'modules'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $moduleDirectory = scandir($modulePath);
            foreach ($moduleDirectory as $dir) {
                $subModuleDirectory = scandir($modulePath.$dir);
                foreach ($subModuleDirectory as $entry) {
                    if (is_dir($modulePath.$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry)) {
                        $directories = scandir($modulePath.$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
                        foreach ($directories as $subDir) {
                            if ($modelName == strtolower($subDir)) {
                                $temp = explode('.', $subDir); // array('User','php')
                                $result = $temp[0];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

**My Question is** : Can this cause any performance issues since i am checking this for every API call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have a map of all the classes in your project. That way you can use that instead of looking on the disk all the time.

Take a look at [composer](http://getcomposer.org/). Yes, I know it is a dependency manager but it is also an excellent [autoload generator](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

If you correctly add a composer.json with for example:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "protected/",
    ]
}
```

in it, it will auto generate a full class map array which you can load from vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php. All you'd have to do is make sure the keys of the array are in lowercase and you can match 1 on 1. Just be sure to **remember calling "composer dump-autoload" if you add new classes**.

If you are doing it this way, consider just loading the complete autoloader instead (vendor/autoload.php) as it will assist Yii as a whole to limit disk searches. Have Yii profit even more from it by doing:

```
$loader = require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
Yii::$classMap = $loader->getClassMap();
```

In your index.php before you call the run() function. 
That way Yii can just look the class up in the array too.

For your problem, just call the $loader->getClassMap() function a second time and lowercase the array keys for your lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

As there are quite some filesystem related functions inside loops in your code, the performance penalty will be heavy due to all the issued syscalls. You should at least cache the result of your method.

An even better method might be [this solution](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22790-check-if-model-exists/page__view__findpost__p__111444) proposed by a Yii core dev :)

Comment: yes YII caching is enabled. but beyond that will it be a performance hit ? is there any other ways to do this with yii ? i went through yii manual and was unable to figure out one.

Comment: Yii caching being enabled is insignificant if your method doesn't make use of it. I've also updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the update but it doesnt help me at all. i already refereed it once. i need to lowercase both classname and the get param and compare as i am doing in e function.

Comment: bcz, param can be either, User, user, USER, USer or any way and still i need to support by lowering.

Comment: Uh. What about `ucfirst(strtolower($modelName))`? That won't help with camel-case classnames, though.

Comment: I have model name with two words and three words.  StructureActivityLog, DeviceModel, User. if all my model names are one word then most probably what you sad is correct. but we can expect all the models to be like that right ?

Comment: Absolutely. If I dare ask: Why is it you need to support case insensitive model names?

Comment: Yeah, good question. the thing is i am using linux server. so i do need a way to check weather file exists or not. anybody can call the API in anyway. some may type www.example.com/api/post where as someother can type www.example.com/api/Post. so i am taking this param in to account and comparing. how can i do this thing without case insensitive matching ?

Comment: If I were you, I'd enfore API calls with names like `user`, `structureActivityLog`, `deviceModel` and so on. Run `ucfirst()` on the modelname and let misspellings be the user's problem.